# How to send gitlab emails with different domains for postfix, smtp and mail relay

Tags: email, gitlab, postfix-mta

I'm trying to get emails working from gitlab via smtp, but I am not sure which domains/FQDN to use in this setup:

Let's assume I have a gitlab server for "coolproject".

- The **gitlab server** can be reached via `coolproject.dyndns.org`
- The **email account** to send from is `gitlab@coolproject.org`
- The **smtp server** is running at a hoster: `smtp.myhoster.com`

Now I'm struggeling to configure postfix correctly. All examples always use "example.com" everywhere, which does not help in this case...

Questions:

- What is "/etc/mailname" (or in /etc/postfix/main.cf: myorigin) supposed to be?
- In /etc/postfix/main.cf: What is mydestination?
- In /etc/postfix/main.cf: What is relayhost?

For the `gitlab.rb` I assume this is correct?

```
 gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.hoster.com"
 gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab@coolproject.org"
 gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "coolproject.org"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was on the right track, but the mail hoster did not accept the settings. I found some `Net::ReadTimeout` errors in my sidekiq log, which pointed me into this direction: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5636

Also, thanks to the gitlab irc chat, I got the hint to disable the smtp_domain.

So, enabling tls, this is my final working configuration

Final configuration:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.hoster.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab@coolproject.org"
# removed gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "coolproject.org"
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
```